# How to reinstall Ubuntu in dual boot with Windows 10?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, windows-10

I have Ubuntu 15.10 and Windows 10 dual-booted, but I want to reinstall Ubuntu in the same partition without making any changes or causing problems in the dual boot option and without removing Windows.  Is it possible? Any guide on how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible and very easy.

1. Make a backup of your personal data which is in `/home/username` where `username` is your actual username. This is less necessary if you have `/home` on a separate partition, but for the sake of safety in case you make any mistake, you should do it.
2. You may make a backup of your Windows also, for the same reason.
3. Assuming now that your data is safe, you just proceed to install as a fresh installation, using the partitions which were in use for Ubuntu in your current installation. If you had a separate `/home`, simply don't format it to save time. It is safe to format everything else, except your Windows partitions.

The Ubuntu installer will be very polite with your current Windows installation and will provide an entry in the boot loader to either boot Windows or Linux when you start.

Comment: That is using the Something Else install option. And choose change to select existing / (root) partition. It will find swap automatically. And if do have the separate /home then be sure NOT to tick the format box.